# Не работает сертификат

Tags: tls, traefik

Запускаю traefik с пример из документации. Не работает `tls`:

```
time="2020-06-23T21:54:24Z" level=error msg="failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
time="2020-06-23T21:54:24Z" level=error msg="Unable to add a certificate to the entryPoint \"https\" : unable to generate TLS certificate : tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
time="2020-06-23T21:54:25Z" level=error msg="failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
```

Конфиг:

```
logLevel = "ERROR"

# Entrypoints to be used by frontends that do not specify any entrypoint.
# Each frontend can specify its own entrypoints.
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https", "auth"]

[web]
# Port for the status page
address = ":8080"

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]
  # http should be redirected to https
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  # https is the default
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "learn.fless.pro.cert"
        keyFile = "learn.fless.pro.key"
  [entryPoints.auth]
    address = ":61295"
    [entryPoints.auth.tls]
#      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
#        certFile = "/home/eurvanov/grader-v2-deploy/traefik/learn.fless.pro.cert"
#        keyFile = "/home/eurvanov/grader-v2-deploy/traefik/learn.fless.pro.key"



# [acme]
# email = "1@bk.ru"
# storageFile = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
# entryPoint = "https"


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "a.b.c"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

Comment: Напрашивается очевидный вопрос: `learn.fless.pro.cert` точно в PEM формате?

Comment: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out learn.fless.pro.cert -keyout learn.fless.pro.key`

Comment: @andreymal А, хз. Я не шарю. Генерил так.

Comment: @andreymal почему именно pem нужен?

Comment: @andreymal не совсем ясно. Почему `pem`, если в конфиге просят указать 2 файлика.

Comment: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out learn.fless.pro.cert -keyout learn.fless.pro.key`

команда правильная - я проверил, что она генерирует сертификаты в правильном формате

Comment: Да, действительно в правильном

Comment: Напрашивается другой очевидный вопрос: а относительные пути точно считаются относительно правильного [текущего] каталога? Я не юзал traefik и возможно несу фигню, но это две первые вещи, которые я бы проверял в подобных случаях. Или абсолютные пути выпилены просто для упрощения примера в вопросе?

Comment: @andreymal да, я пути проверил. Но, после запуска traefik, всё равно всё работает не по https.

Comment: https://youtu.be/9fGGddwU2w8?t=562

Comment: Что странно. Человек, по ссылке выше делает то же самое, что и я. Но я так и не увидел в видео, чтобы он начал ходить по https. Может, я что-то не понимаю и tls -- это не про https?

Comment: @andreymal а где Вы увидели относительные пути?

Comment: @hedgehogues `certFile = "learn.fless.pro.cert"` очень даже относительный

Comment: @andreymal нет, я пробовал и здесь тоже абсолютные ставить. Не работает. Разумеется, абсолютный путь внутри докера.